# Does cannot lock ref error in git cause any problems?

Tags: git, refs

I got this error when pushing to a repo:

```
error: cannot  lock ref 'refs/head/master' is at <some number> but expected <some number> on <repository link>
```

Though the code is pushed, does that error cause any problems?